# Rails elasticsearch on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, searchkick

I used searchkick in my app, but on Heroku I have an error

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

I read that I have to use add-ons e.g. Found or SearchBox, but I cannot add my credit cart to my heroku account, so i can't use add-ons.
Are there any options to make my searchkick works without add-ons?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to do that without credit card.
I did it using the bonsai addon.

https://addons.heroku.com/bonsai